# Massively downloading images by javascript does not work in IOS

Tags: javascript, php, prestashop

The problem is that instead of downloading them, it opens the first one and no longer does anything else, it happens only with iOS, Chrome and Firefox.

In Safari it works well although it only downloads the first image and it does not massively download 3-4.

**code**

```
function downloadAll() {
  var urls = [ {/literal}{$imagUrl2 nofilter}{literal} ];
  var names = [ {/literal}{$imagName nofilter}{literal} ];

  var link = document.createElement('a');
  link.style.display = 'none';

  document.body.appendChild(link);

  for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
    link.setAttribute('download', names[i]);
    link.setAttribute('href', urls[i]);
    link.click();
  }

  document.body.removeChild(link);
}
```

Comment: You may have more chance to get your question answered if you post it [here](https://es.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: Las preguntas y respuestas aquí deben estar escritas en inglés. Por favor utiliza http://es.stackoverflow.com. (Questions and answers here must be written in English. Please use https://es.stackoverflow.com/.)